# How do you specify default Spring MVC method for wildcard accept header

Tags: spring-mvc, mime-types

Using Spring MVC 3.2, I have defined two methods in two different controllers with the following produces annotations:

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces={
        "application/vnd.myresource.v1+json", 
        "application/vnd.myresource.v1+xml"
    })
public ResponseEntity getResourceMethod_v1()
{
.......
}

@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces={
        "application/vnd.myresource.v2+json", 
        "application/vnd.myresource.v2+xml"
    })
public ResponseEntity getResourceMethod_v2()
{
.......
}
```

When I specify "accept: application/vnd.myresource.v1+json" in the request header, Spring maps correctly to the first method.  And, when I specify "accept: application/vnd.myresource.v2+json" in the request header, Spring maps correctly to the second method.  However, when I don't specify "accept:" in the request header (the request defaults to "accept: */*"), Spring maps to the first method.

How can I specify the second method as the default mapping for Spring?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I can add the MediaType.ALL_VALUE to the produces block of the method that I want to be the default.

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces={
        "application/vnd.myresource.v1+json", 
        "application/vnd.myresource.v1+xml"
    })
public ResponseEntity getResourceMethod_v1()
{
.......
}

@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces={
        MediaType.ALL_VALUE,
        "application/vnd.myresource.v2+json", 
        "application/vnd.myresource.v2+xml"
    })
public ResponseEntity getResourceMethod_v2()
{
.......
}
```